# Quick way for copying link to file or folder for people with existing access (Sharepoint/Office365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

I often want to create a link to a Sharepoint/O365 file or folder that I use in meeting notes, wiki pages, etc. For files that I have synced to my local file system using the OneDrive Client, I can do so by the following procedure in Windows explorer:

1. Right-click on the file or folder
2. Click on "Share"
3. Select "People with existing access" from the drop-down menu
4. Hit "Apply"
5. Click on "Copy link"

This takes up quite a bit of time. Is there a shortcut or some other quick way of getting the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with some OneDrive version prior to 23.124.0613, this feature was added to the Windows Explorer integration. There now is a command "Copy link" in the context menu below the "Share" command.

However, the links created by this way are not persistent. They break if the file or its path is renamed or moved. See [Create persistent link for "People with existing access"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/308395/97228)

Answer (score 1):

Per my test,in SharePoint Admin center there is currently not supported to set **people with existing access** by default, however we can set it through powershell:

```
Set-SPOSite -identity https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/YourSite -DefaultLinkToExistingAccess 1
```

After using this command, it is set as a user with existing permissions by default.
Then when copying the link, click the **copy link** to slightly reduce troubles:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll talk to my admin to try this.

Comment: How are things going? Is there any update?If you think my suggestion is helpful, you could mark it as an answer. It will help others who meet the similar question in this forum.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have so far not reached someone in our company with the rights to do this. As soon as we've tested it, I'll surely vote it up.

Comment: Btw, I was more looking for a way stating directly off Windows explorer. Having to first navigate to the web site is not necessarily shorter than the way described in the question. It's definitely still a help, but from a different starting point.

Comment: I cannot confirm that this is what our admin did, but the functionality you mention works now. As the original post asked for a solution from Windows Explorer, I won't mark it as an answer to this question. But I upvoted it as it is surely a help in some situations.