# Create persistent link for "People with existing access"

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

When I create a link to a sharepoint file by sharing it with "People you choose", "People in ", (and probably "Anyone", but this is disabled by my organization), I get a persistent link. I.e. the link still works if I rename the file and/or move it within my sharepoint site.
However, if I create a link for "People with existing access", the link contains the path to the file. This path is not persistent. Changing file name or path will break the link.

Is there a way to create a persistent link without having to open up the file to anyone in my organization or manually specifying all the people that have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

"People with existing access" sharing link is effective for existing permissions of specific document, so it will be affected by file renaming.

Per my knowledge, there is no option to create a persistent link without anyone access or manually set specific people.